# Using item in ng-repeat as a parameter in function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How does one correctly pass ng-repeat item as a parameter to a function? I'm showing both relevant html and js also the error that it gives.

html:

```
<div class="swiper-slide" data-ng-repeat="items in (ctrl.cur_level || ctrl.first_level)">
                <div class = "item" data-ng-repeat="item in items" data-ng-click="!ctrl.isWorkDay(item.lane.title)||ctrl.select(item)" data-ng-disabled="isWorkDay(item.lane.title)" >
                  <div class="{{ctrl.workingDayClass(item.lane.title)}}" >
                    <button>{{ item.num }}</button>
                    <span data-ng-if="item.lane" class="title">{{ item.lane.title }}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

js:

```
 isWorkDay: (title) ->
      enabled = true
      d = new Date();
      n = $this.weekday[d.getDay()];
      if(n=="Sunday" or n=="Saturday")
        if(isInArray(title, $this.freeServices))
          enabled = false
      else
        if(title == "Дежурный врач")
          enabled = false
      console.log("item_inner "+$this.item_inner)
      return enabled
isInArray: (value, array) ->
  array.indexOf(value) > -1;

workingDayClass: (title)->
  console.log("title "+title)
  item_inner = "item_inner"
  d = new Date();
  n = $this.weekday[d.getDay()];
  if(n=="Sunday" or n=="Saturday")
    if(isInArray(title, $this.freeServices))
      item_inner = "item_inner_disabled"
  else
    if(title == "Дежурный врач")
      item_inner = "item_inner_disabled"
  return item_inner
```

Error:

> [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate:
>   {{ctrl.workingDayClass(item.lane.title)}} ReferenceError: isInArray is
>   not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **$this.isInArray** instead of **isInArray**

this

```
if(isInArray(title, $this.freeServices))
```

should be

```
if($this.isInArray(title, $this.freeServices))
```

Cheers!